# pandas: sequential merge adds new columns instead of replacing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df_all = pd.DataFrame(columns=["uid", "a", "b"], data=[["uid1", 12, 15],
                                                    ["uid2", 13, 16],
                                                    ["uid3", 14, 17],
                                                    ["uid4", 15, 18]])

df_additional_info1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["uid", "c", "d"], data=[["uid1", 12, 15],
                                                                   ["uid3", 14, 17]])

df_additional_info2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["uid", "c", "d"], data=[["uid2", 12, 15]])
```

I need to merge **df_all** twice with additional information. First with df_additional_info1, then with df_additional_info2 and so on. **They will always contain additional info for already existing rows and only for those rows that were not yet updated.**

When I do following:

```py
df_all = df_all.merge(df_additional_info1, how="left", on="uid")
df_all = df_all.merge(df_additional_info2, how="outer", on="uid")
```

I get duplicated columns (*_x, *_y):

[image: what I get]

But I need this
[image: what I need]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you `.concat` the additional info dfs and left merge that?

Comment: nice workaround. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([df_all.set_index('uid'), df_additional_info1.set_index('uid'),
            df_additional_info2.set_index('uid')])
 .stack().unstack().reset_index())
```

---

Alternatively,

```
(df_additional_info2.set_index('uid')
 .combine_first(
     pd.concat([df_all.set_index('uid'), 
                df_additional_info1.set_index('uid')], axis=1))
 .reset_index())
```

EXPLANATION:

The code first sets `uid` as the index for all DataFrames, facilitating the merging operations. It concatenates `df_all` and `df_additional_info1` along the column axis using `pd.concat()`, appending `df_additional_info1`'s columns to `df_all` and creating a DataFrame containing all columns from both, filling with `NaN` for `uids` absent in `df_additional_info1`. `combine_first()` then replaces any null values in `df_additional_info2` with values from the concatenated DataFrame, essentially filling in `df_additional_info2`'s gaps with data from `df_all` and `df_additional_info1`, based on `uid`. The final step, `reset_index()`, moves `uid` back to a regular column and reestablishes the default integer index, producing a merged DataFrame with all available additional information.

---

Output:

```
    uid   a   b     c     d
0  uid1  12  15  12.0  15.0
1  uid2  13  16  12.0  15.0
2  uid3  14  17  14.0  17.0
3  uid4  15  18   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: First way seems to be very elegant - thanks. But I have troubles to decode the second way...

Comment: You are welcome, @HonzaS. Please, see the explanation I have just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.concat` the additional info frames:

```
df_all.merge(
   pd.concat([df_additional_info1, df_additional_info2]),
   how = "left"
)
```

```
    uid   a   b     c     d
0  uid1  12  15  12.0  15.0
1  uid2  13  16  12.0  15.0
2  uid3  14  17  14.0  17.0
3  uid4  15  18   NaN   NaN
```